# Using NGINX as reverse proxy for appliaction servers accessible from one ip address but two different ports

Tags: nginx, odoo, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to use nginx as a reverse proxy for my Odoo deployment. Indeed I have two instances accessible respectively on port 8069 and 8090. Is it possible to configure nginx for these two instances given that I have only IP address (I don't want to use a domain name)?

I have tried something like this:

```
server{
   listen 80 default_server;
   server_name my_ip_address/instance1;

   location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
   }

}

server{
   listen 80;
   server_name my_ip_address/instance2;

   location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8099;
   }

}
```

And I have tried also

```
server{
   listen 80 default_server;
   server_name my_ip_address;

   location /instance1 {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
   }

}

server{
   listen 80;
   server_name my_ip_address;

   location /instance2 {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8099;
   }

}
```

But when I try to access my_ip_address/instance1 or my_ip_address/instance2 neither is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is something possible as you have to rewrite the paths to `assets` and `form` actions as well.

`assets` include all the javascript and CSS files as well as the images.

`form` actions are where the data of a form should be redirected.

so for example when you `login` to the system, the login form sends the data to `/web/login` action.

how are you going to handle this? and in which virtual host of your virtual hosts?!

On the other hand, try to use subdomains.
or if you have to use IPs, then use 2 IPs referring to the same server and redirect each IP used in as host to one of your instances.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by : I don't think this is something possible as you have to rewrite the paths to assets and form actions as well.

On the other hand I'll give a try to the notion of two IPs pointing to the same server since I don't want to use subdomains

Comment: let's take the css files to include in the web page as example:
`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/web/static/lib/bootstrap/scss/web.assets_common/_functions.scss.css">`
this element is taken from a real Odoo v12.0 page. we will you route this when the browser send a request to the nginx? which instance to choose ? same thing goes for the javascript and ajax requests!
you will have to change that in your Odoo codebase and have 2 different versions of odoo each will make all ajax requests to specific server as well as the links to javascript, css and images.

Comment: if I may ask about the reason why you don't want to use sub-domains? I might be able to help you with a better idea !

Comment: 1. Yeah this may be an issue, but with 2 IPs i think this won't be any longer a problem as you suggested.
2. I just don't have a domain for now.

Comment: so have you tried working with 2 IPs without the the path prefix?! did it work?

Comment: Finally I went with sub-domains

Comment: happy that your issue is resolved, could you please mark this answer as helpful answer?!